# ASP.NET/MVC Bundler Cache does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, bundle

In an MVC5 project we encounter a problem with caching of the bundled resources (js/css).

According to the [mvc docs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification), by default the bundles should be cached. And it works in other projects. However, here, no matter what configurations, the response headers for our resources are

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 11:22:11 GMT
Expires: -1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I can't figure out where this is coming from as we are not disabling cache anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: did you review the HTTP headers configured in IIS? I don't remember if headers set in IIS would override the ones set by ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks, @Luizgrs. Yes, I have checked the settings. there is no header configuration. I have even created a new website, it din't help. If I run with debug="true", correct headers are sent for _some_ resources. The less bundle always is un-cached though. :/

Comment: Please check Global.asax maybe some of your teammates set programatically 'not caching' content code.

Comment: OMG. You are right, Piotr! In Application_BeginRequest:
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment Igor claimed that in Global.asax there were code for disabling caching:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);   
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1)); 
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Igor just to inform you these lines is one of the suggested way to fix 'browser back button' scenario (but as you can see with some cons). Simple scenario steps:

1. Login to application - looged in user is redirected to the home page
2. Logout - user redirected to the login page
3. Click back browser button - User should not be redirected to the home page but with enabled caching it could be an issue.

Please check the back browser button funcionality. If the scenario which I wrote is a problem for you please just use atribute

```
[OutputCache]
```

with proper parameters.

Regards Piotr